# Error in GROUP BY clause. Unable to parse query text

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a complex SQL statement that I fall upon an error. They prompted me this error: Error in GROUP BY expression. Can't parse query text.

I pasted this SQL statement which causes this error. Can anyone advise me where went wrong? Any ideas???

```
SELECT        AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour1, Hour2, Hour3, Hour4, Hour5, Hour6, Hour7, Hour8, Hour9, Hour10, Hour11, Hour12, EmpName, ShiftTime, 
                     BreakTime, SignIn, SignOut
FROM            (SELECT        z.AllocationDate, z.LocationName, z.StationName, a.Hour1, b.Hour2, c.Hour3, d .Hour4, e.Hour5, f.Hour6, g.Hour7, h.Hour8, i.Hour9, j.Hour10, k.Hour11, 
                                                l.Hour12, m.EmpName, m.ShiftTime, m.BreakTime, m.SignIn, m.SignOut
                      FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName
                                                FROM            satsschema.viewmain
                                                WHERE        (StationName IS NOT NULL)) z LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour1
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view00000100) a ON z.LocationName = a.LocationName AND z.StationName = a.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = a.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour2
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view01000200) b ON z.LocationName = b.LocationName AND z.StationName = b.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = b.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour3
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view02000300) c ON z.LocationName = c.LocationName AND z.StationName = c.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = c.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour4
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view03000400) d ON z.LocationName = d .LocationName AND z.StationName = d .StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = d .AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour5
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view04000500) e ON z.LocationName = e.LocationName AND z.StationName = e.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = e.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour6
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view05000600) f ON z.LocationName = f.LocationName AND z.StationName = f.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = f.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour7
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view06000700) g ON z.LocationName = g.LocationName AND z.StationName = g.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = g.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour8
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view07000800) h ON z.LocationName = h.LocationName AND z.StationName = h.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = h.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour9
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view08000900) i ON z.LocationName = i.LocationName AND z.StationName = i.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = i.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour10
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view09001000) j ON z.LocationName = j.LocationName AND z.StationName = j.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = j.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour11
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view10001100) k ON z.LocationName = k.LocationName AND z.StationName = k.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = k.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour12
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view11001200) l ON z.LocationName = l.LocationName AND z.StationName = l.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = l.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT        a.EmpName, CONCAT(b.StartTime, ' - ', b.EndTime) AS ShiftTime, CONCAT(a.EmpTime, ' - ', ADDTIME(a.EmpTime, '0 1:0:0.000000')) 
                                                                                AS BreakTime, a.Break, a.EmployeeOnBreak, '' AS SignIn, '' AS SignOut
                                                      FROM            satsschema.employeeslot a, satsschema.ufis b
                                                      WHERE        a.UFISEmpGroup = b.UFISID 
                                                     GROUP BY EmpName) m) Morning
WHERE        (AllocationDate = @AllocationDate) AND (LocationName = @LocationName) AND (StationName <> '') AND (Break = 1)
GROUP BY StationName, LocationName, AllocationDate
```

Comment: Make sure the parameters values you pass are enclosed with '' if they are not a number

Comment: You mean which one? I kinda new to this kind of complex SQL statements.

Comment: Can you run a profiler and see what is the final executed query?

Comment: This select statements could be run in MySQL workbench but when I transfer to Visual Studio, using these select statement to create dataset, it comes out this error " Error in GROUP BY clause. Unable to parse query text "

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing a lot of concepts. 
You can't use a group by without an aggregation function like Min, Max, Avg, etc.

If you want to use Group By, you have to tell what to do with these non aggregated fields:

Hour1, Hour2, Hour3, Hour4, Hour5, Hour6, Hour7, Hour8, Hour9, Hour10, Hour11, Hour12, EmpName, ShiftTime, BreakTime, SignIn, SignOut

I think that what you want is an ORDER BY and not a GROUP BY.

Comment: I've have editted the code to ORDER BY EmpName but when I run it, it shows this error, " Error in WHERE clause near 'ORDER'.
Unable to parse query text. " Care to explain what this error means?\

Comment: It is a syntax error... you have to check query by query. It can be an open ' or ). You are not using Group By correctly in the sub-queries too. Test the sub queries one by one, this can help to find the one with error.

Answer (score 0):

Only Aggregate function or grouped columns can be selected in outer query, if you wanna do this.
You can use that columns in group by.

`...
GROUP BY AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour1, Hour2, Hour3, Hour4, Hour5, Hour6, Hour7, Hour8, Hour9, Hour10, Hour11, Hour12, EmpName, ShiftTime, 
                     BreakTime, SignIn, SignOut`

Thanks.